# cPanel / WHM restore from backup tar archive (from another cPanel server)

Tags: migration, cpanel, whm

I am quite new to server migrations, but fairly familiar with cPanel though. My current task is to migrate an entire website from a server with cPanel to another one.

**What I did so far:**

- Use the Backup Wizard on the old server to create a full backup archive, and FTP it to the new server.
- The full archive (about 6 GB because there are a lot of images) is now in my new server's public_html directory.

Now, what I need is a way to make the server take this tar archive, which is a full backup, and restore from it.

**What I tried:**

- I tried simply extracting the archive, but it is taking forever to finish (again the archive is 6 GB), and for some reason my browser tab has to stay open until the end of the process, otherwise the extracting halts.
- Also, as I have WHM access, I tried the "Restore a Full Backup/cpmove File" option, but for some reason, under the "Username for the account that you wish to restore:" textbox, WHM does not find my cPanel username.

If anyone can either tell me what I am doing wrong, or propose another option, I would really appreciate it.

P.S.: I only have WHM access to the new server, not the old one.

**Edit:** I got the WHM method working now. My mistake was that my tar archive **was not stored in the `/home` directory, but in the home directory of the cPanel user (which is `/home/username`)!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your cpanel full backup file to /home directory and if you root have access of the server use below command as  /scripts/restorepkg  (cpanel username )

OR

Login to WHM with root user and go through the steps mentioned on below URL.

http://documentation.cpanel.net:8090/display/68Docs/Restore+a+Full+Backup+cpmove+File

Comment: Yes, that is what I ended up doing. My mistake was that my tar archive was not stored in the `/home` directory, but in `/home/username` directory.